# How to unlock an iCloud account

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

My apple iCloud is locked for security reasons, when I try to unlock it using my recovery gmail account, I don't see the link sent to me.

I mailed to the iTunes Store customer suport team more than thrice where they gave me steps to follow but still I couldnt unlock my account. I can't update my apps or backup them.

Even if I create a new Apple ID, the old one is stuck to the apple store, popping and asking for password.

Comment: Are you really sure the email you are using is correct?

Comment: Which steps did you get from Apple, what happened when following them (especially where did they fail)?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had any luck with email support, you should call AppleCare. They can unlock the account.